# log4net file extension

Tags: log4net

I am working on an application which uses log4net extensivly. I have noticed that once the log file gets to big it starts out with .log, .log.1 , .log.2 , .log.3 , and so on. How do i get it to just say  .log and not .log.X .

Comment: You should check out this setting: PreserveLogFileNameExtension. Please note that as of Sep 29, 11, you'll need to download and build the latest source. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643759/rollingfileappender-preserve-the-file-extension-without-log4net-patch

Comment: possible duplicate of [log4net rolling file appender file name format when maximumFileSize reached](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503784/log4net-rolling-file-appender-file-name-format-when-maximumfilesize-reached)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the log is configured to use a RollingFileAppender.  That keeps log files until a configured maximum size is hit.  The log is saved with the .1, .2, etc. extensions and a new one is created.

If you want to just keep appending, try looking at the FileAppender.

Here's a link to some config examples.
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html