# RollingFileAppender: preserve the file extension without log4net patch

Tags: log4net, rollingfileappender

M question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608591/log4net-rollingfileappender-size-rollingstyle-file-extension) as I have the same problem. How can I make the RollingFileAppender of log4net preserve the file extension without having to actually "patch" (i.e. create an interim build of the current trunk) log4net? How could I achieve the same thing by overriding the RollingFileAppender or creating any other extension with the least effort?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608591/log4net-rollingfileappender-size-rollingstyle-file-extension/2615557#2615557), you're not required to "patch" or change anything in log4net. You cannot use the 1.2.10 release, though. It is a rather old build, but the `PreserveLogFileNameExtension` is in [the current source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/). You only have to bring down the source and compile the dll yourself and you're good to go.

**Update:** I see your concern. IMO, the only way is to make a build and test it. To further your confidence you could review [the current list of resolved (and unresolved) issues](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&jqlQuery=fixVersion%20=%20%221.2.11%22%20AND%20project%20=%20LOG4NET) for 1.2.11. I would think that seeing they are not doing a major revision, changes are mainly bug fixes and additional features.

Comment: Ok, let's not call it "patch" then. I am a little bit afraid of introducing a newer version of log4net because so many components (including 3rd party) of our system rely on log4net. How can I make sure that that new build doesn't break anything? What is the release and ceckin story here? Does the current source in svn qualify as release/stable? I don't see any official releases after 1.2.10. What happened to 1.2.11?