# log4net rolling file appender file name format when maximumFileSize reached

Tags: log4net, rollingfileappender

We're using the log4net rolling file appender and have the following requirements for our log files:

- A new log file at the start of each day, with the date in the filename
- A maximum log file size of 500KB

The issue we are having is the file naming strategy when files hit 500KB: they get renamed with a `.1` suffix. This is problematic as it breaks file association in Windows, so opening the files is (slightly) more of a chore.

The configuration we're using is:

```xml
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="c:\log\path" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <datePattern value=".yyyy-MM-dd.lo\g" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="50" />
  <maximumFileSize value="500KB" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Is there support for specifying the naming strategy used when our files hit the `maximumFileSize`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Version 1.2.11 of log4net includes the [PreserveLogFileNameExtension](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/?topic=html/P_log4net_Appender_RollingFileAppender_PreserveLogFileNameExtension.htm) property on the `RollingFileAppender`.  Setting the property to true will allow files to be rolled in the format logName.roll#.fileExt, keeping your file associations intact.

The entry inside the appender block would look like:
`<param name="PreserveLogFileNameExtension" value="true" />`

Comment: Can this used like: <appender>.....<PreserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>...</appender>

Comment: @ch.smrutiranjanparida - Answer is updated for your question.

Comment: Actually inside an appender-block the syntax shouldn't be `param name` but `<preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />`