# Log4net rolling filenames

Tags: c#, log4net, filenames

I'm using log4net in a C# application

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="..\logs\Program.log.xml" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10000KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j">
        <conversionPattern value="%utcdate [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

The problem I have is that my logfiles are being renamed -

```
Program.log.xml.1
Program.log.xml.2
```

So the files dont open if the correct file viewer easily, I'd prefer the files be renamed -

```
Program.log.1.xml
Program.log.2.xml
```

I've searched the documentation, & can't see this or don't understand it.
Thanks all.

Comment: Your answer is here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503784/log4net-rolling-file-appender-file-name-format-when-maximumfilesize-reached

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the preserveLogFileNameExtension option to your config:

```
<preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
```

Comment: .. for log4net version >= 1.2.11